# Good free polling software?

Tags: web-apps, polls

I'm looking to start Movie Mondays with my friends, and am looking for a good poll site to track what to watch next. The style I'm looking for is the same as polls within Facebook events, however I want it to be able to be independent of an event.

It should have to be able to:

- Have a list of options that can be expanded by my friends (if they
  have a new movie that they'd want to watch, they should be able to
  add it to the poll)
- Track answers and people (e.g. if Pete says he wants to watch x and y movies, the next time Pete checks, his answers should be there)
- Modify answers (e.g. if Pete votes on something, then Kate adds another movie, Pete should be able to vote on the new movie while
  still keeping his old votes)
- Delete options (e.g. I'd like to delete options or mark them as archived if we already watched the movie)
- Display the "live" standings so everyone can see how the vote is going at all times
- Should be free

I've checked Google forms (I didn't like it because you have to Submit your answers so you can't see the results) and Facebook polls (ideal, except they are restricted to a single event), Doodles (the free version is mostly good for scheduling, couldn't find a way for users to add their own movies) and some other online tools based on a Google search that didn't quite fit the expectations (mostly you either couldn't see the results, track users or add new options).

Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for "polls" and found these.

- SurveyMonkey.com
- EasyPolls.net
- DirectPoll.com
- StatPak.com

Rather than a specific site, I recommend using a Wiki where everyone can add, change, and share the site equally in a public or private environment. Little effort is necessary to set things up just the way you want them.

Have a look at [pbworks.com](https://plans.pbworks.com)

Answer (score 1):

Survey monkey is really easy and you can set more advanced metrics. I have used it in market research and it has everything you need and you can even do A/B testing for different questions. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure: I work for PollUnit as a developer.**

You can take a look at [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com). It is free for teams with up to 40 members.

I think the image poll combined with a star rating and the link feature could be great for you. You could upload movie posters, link a trailer and rate them with stars. Of course there is also a simple yes/no option or you can write just the movie name instead of a picture.

I attach an example. This is a logo voting i created a few months ago, i think it explains what I mean. The beer background is just one of many themes provided by PollUnit.

[image: screenshot of PollUnit in a web browser]

You find further poll examples here: https://pollunit.com/en/voting

The functions that you have desired should all be fulfilled. Your participants should make an account so that they can adjust their votes / re-vote from different devices.